# jQuery Ajax request in Sharepoint 2007 (SOAP)

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint, soap, sharepoint-2007

I have the following web service:

```
SOAP 1.1

The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

POST /_vti_bin/QuickLinks.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: myintracomm-design.ec.europa.eu
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://ec.europa.eu/GetSuggestions"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSuggestions xmlns="http://ec.europa.eu/">
      <prefixText>string</prefixText>
      <count>int</count>
    </GetSuggestions>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSuggestionsResponse xmlns="http://ec.europa.eu/">
      <GetSuggestionsResult>
        <string>string</string>
        <string>string</string>
      </GetSuggestionsResult>
    </GetSuggestionsResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Which I locate by navigating to a url like:

http://www.bla.eu/_vti_bin/QuickLinks.asmx?op=GetSuggestions

I tried to make an Ajax request to fetch the content lying behind this, by using this code:

```
var productServiceUrl = 'http://myintracomm-design.ec.europa.eu/_vti_bin/QuickLinks.asmx?op=GetSuggestions';

function LoadData() {
    var soapEnv = 
    '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
           <soap:Body> \
              <GetSuggestions xmlns="http://ec.europa.eu/"> \
              <prefixText>sys</prefixTest> \
              <count>10</count> \
              </GetSuggestions> \
             </soap:Body> \
        </soap:Envelope>';

    $jQuery.ajax({
        url: productServiceUrl,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: OnLinksFetched,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}

function OnLinksFetched(xmlHttpRequest, status)
    {
     $jQuery(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML)
        .find('GetSuggestionsResult')
        .each(function() {
       var name = $jQuery(this).find('Name').text();
       $jQuery("#links").append(name);
     });}
```

and I added an simple onclick event to a link (just for testing purposes). Unfortunately, I get a bad request error.[image: here is the error in action]
I tried many combinations of the soap request (as I have no experience in SOAP) but with no success. Decided to post here after 5 days of effort. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a request header to your web service call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: productServiceUrl,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",
        "http://ec.europa.eu/GetSuggestions"
    },
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml",
    data: soapEnv,
    complete: OnLinksFetched,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
});
```

Comment: I get a  " Uncaught ReferenceError: LoadData is not defined
(anonymous function) "